# texshop does not generate pdf, only dvi

Tags: pdftex, texshop

I have had no problem with texshop generating pdf files until I tried a new template today. When it compiles, texshop only generates dvi, not pdf. Any clues or suggestions? I clicked "typeset" with the drop down "Latex". There is no pdfLatex in my texshop.

The tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url} % not crucial - just used below for the URL 



\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.5in}%
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}%
\addtolength{\textheight}{-.3in}%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.8in}%


\begin{document}


\def\spacingset#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}%
{#1}\small\normalsize} \spacingset{1}



\newpage
\spacingset{1.45} % DON'T change the spacing!
\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

Body of paper.  Margins in this document are roughly 0.75 inches all
around, letter size paper.



\bibliographystyle{Chicago}

\bibliography{Bibliography-MM-MC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Those are the very first lines of the file?

Comment: There should be a menu which has compile options.  One of them should read something like `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` pdflatex always compiles to pdf  Your example compiles fine.

Comment: Somebody who uses a mac will most likely be able to help. Try using an alternative editor to rule out a problem with your TeX setup.  A good one is TeXStudio http://www.texstudio.org/ which works on mac.  Or you can try compiling at the command line.

Comment: Did you really show the complete document?

Comment: You guys are right. I did not show the very first line of the tex file, which I thought was a comment and can be ignored. 
The very first line is %&latex. 
Once I delete this line, I get pdf! Why? I thought everything that begins with a % is treated as a comment.

Comment: Thank you for posting a working example! At the same time, much of your code does not seem to be relevant to the question you're asking here. Please limit the example to only the code required for your issue to appear. You can have a look at [this guide for how to prune your code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225) for this purpose. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX engines (the binaries which actually compile your document) recognise certain special comments in the very first line of the file. This works as several apparently different processes all resolve to the same underlying binary. In particular, both `pdflatex` and `latex` use the same binary, pdfTeX, but with different settings. If you have a first line that reads

```
% &latex
```

this is treated as though you gave the command

```
pdftex "&latex"
```

which means 'use the pdfTeX binary with the LaTeX format in DVI mode', even when you run `pdflatex` (which is the same as `pdftex "&pdflatex"`).

This special parsing of the first line can be disabled, but normally it's only present if it's deliberately inserted (there are use cases where it is helpful).